# How to append a value at the end of each line obtained with grep

Tags: terminal, grep, append, cut

I have some CSV files that I would like to parse with grep (or some other function from terminal) in order to extract some informations.
They are in this form:

```
* Comment 1
* Comment line 2 explaining what the following numbers mean
1000000 ; 3208105 ; 0.18 ; 0.45 ; 0.00015 ; 0.1485 ; 0.03 ; 1 ; 1 ; 5 ; 477003 ; 

* Comment 3
* Comment 4 explaining the meaning of the following lines

* Comment 5
0; 706520; p; 30.4983
1; 20859; p; 57.8
2; 192814; p; 111.842
3; 344542; p; 130.543
4; 54605; p; 131.598
5; 64746; d; 140.898
6; 442082; p; 214.11
7; 546701; p; 249.167
8; 298394; p; 305.034
9; 81188; p; 305.034
.......
```

In each file there could be at most one line in which the third field is equal to `d` instead of `p`. So either there is a line containing a `d` or there is none.

I have a lot of files like this and what I would like to do is extract from each file the line (if present) containing the letter `d` and append after this line the last parameter of the first not-comment line, that in this example would be `47703`.

Up to now I managed to extract separately the lines I need.

With this I can extract every line containing a `d` from every file I have:

```
grep -h -E ' d;' *.csv > output.csv
```

And with this I can extract exactly the number `47703` from a file like the one in the example:

```
grep -v -e "^*" -e " p; " -e " d; " example_file.csv | cut -d \; -f 11
```

But I don't know how to put these two together.

The final output I would like to obtain from the example at the beginning is a single line like this:

```
5; 64746; d; 140.898; 47703
```

and I would like to have a line like this for every CSV file in the current directory.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I did. The input is the first example and the output is the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used for loop to loop all .csv files and assign returned values from your greps to variables, that are concatenated at end of each loop echoed:

`` for f in *.csv ; do value=`grep -v -e "^*" -e " p; " -e " d; " -e '^\s*$' "$f" | cut -d \; -f 11` ; line=`grep -h -E ' d;' "$f" ; echo "$line;$value" ; done ``

Edit: (I also added `-e '^\s*$'` to first grep, that gets line with values on first not commented line. Before, it matched empty lines)

this only echoes lines like `5; 64746; d; 140.898; 47703`, that you wanted. If you want to redirect it to some file (all found lines will be in single output file), you can add it to last echo in that long command, like:

`` for f in *.csv ; do value=`grep -v -e "^*" -e " p; " -e " d; " -e '^\s*$' "$f" | cut -d \; -f 11` ; line=`grep -h -E ' d;' "$f" ; echo "$line;$value" > output.csv ; done ``

for readability, same code on multiple lines:

```
for f in *.csv
do 
    value=`grep -v -e "^*" -e " p; " -e " d; " -e '^\s*$' "$f" | cut -d \; -f 11`
    line=`grep -h -E ' d;' "$f"
    echo "$line;$value"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for `sed`:

*parse.sed* (GNU sed)

```sed
/^ +$/d                          # Ignore empty lines
/^[ 0-9;.]+$/h                   # Save first "number-only" line to hold space
/ d; / {                         # Run block on lines containing ' d; '
  G                              # Copy saved line to pattern space
  s/\n.*; ([0-9]+) *; *$/; \1/   # Append the last number on the second line
  p                              # to the first line and print the result
}
```

*parse.sed* (portable sed)

```sed
# Ignore empty lines
/^ +$/d                          

# Save first "number-only" line to hold space
/^[ 0-9;.]+$/h                   

# Run block on lines containing ' d; '
/ d; / {                         

  # Copy saved line to pattern space
  G                              

  # Append the last number on the second line
  # to the first line and print the result
  s/\n.*; ([0-9]+) *; *$/; \1/   
  p                              
}
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -Enf parse.sed infile.csv
```

Output:

```
5; 64746; d; 140.898; 477003
```

Note that this assumes you only have one line containing the character group `[ 0-9;.]` in the file.

To run this on all local csv files do the following:

```
sed -Enf parse.sed *.csv
```

Comment: When I try to run this to a single file it gives me the error `sed: 1: parse.sed: extra characters at the end of d command`

Comment: @jackscorrow: Sorry, I did not test the script in BSD sed. See the added portable version

Comment: Ok, now it works. Thanks! As soon as I can I'll try your solution and see which one's better